# InvalidArgumentException Unexpected data found когда я пытаюсь сохранить дату публикации

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Задача: Если пользователь не вводил дату публикации, то ставится текущее время, иначе его данные.

Форма

```
@if($publishedDate === 1)
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('published_at',"Дата публикации :") !!}
    {!! Form::input('datetime-local', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d H:i'), [
        'class' => 'form-control',
         'min' => date('Y-m-d')
     ]) !!}
</div>
```

Модель News

```
 public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date) {
    //dd($date);
    if($date === null) {
        //dd($date);
        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') )
            ->copy()->format('F j, Y @ g:i A');
    }

}
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'body',
    'published_at',
    'updated_at',
    'news_wall',
    'slug'
];
protected $dates = ['published_at', 'updated_at'];
```

При том, что функция которая делает то же самое для другого поля работает хорошо

```
public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['updated_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: а зачем еще вот это `->copy()->format('F j, Y @ g:i A')` ?

Comment: Это уже попытка скопировать с гугла то, что работает у других. 
Вот мой код: 
$this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->toDateTimeString();

Comment: Пробовал и так: 
$this->attributes['updated_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', Carbon::now())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: все должно прекрасно работать и так: `attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::now();`

Comment: а когда из данных формы, то так: `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $date)` только формат должен соответствовать тому, что приходит от формы в переменной $date

Comment: В таком формате приходит с формы: "2018-07-27T21:15".
dd(Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')); - "2018-07-19T22:04:35"
$this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); - возвращает ту же ошибку.

Comment: Даже добавил в модель protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s';

Comment: если приходит в таком формате: "2018-07-27T21:15", то нужно так: `$this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i', $date)`

Comment: В таком приходит "2018-07-20T22:20:27"